# Angular 6 component re-binding

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an Angular Component named Dashboard. This component displays a dashboard page with data. I also have a menu component. When I am in the dashboard page, I click on a menu item and it opens up a popup screen. The popup is nothing but a hidden div that can be made visible/invisible. I added a new transaction item in this pop up, saving it to the database and closing the popup after displaying an information alert.

What I wanted is to ensure the dashboard is able to refresh or rebind with the newly added data immediately after hitting save in the pop up.

I tried the following:
1) Use Router.Navigate. My browser URL was always localhost:4200/Dashboard and this code does not seem to reload the route

```
saveTransaction() {
this.addTnxBtn = true;
this.services.addTransaction(this.newTnx).subscribe((data) => {
  if (data.mStatus == "Success") {
    this.success = true;
    this.addTnxBtn = false;
    this.Failed = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  } else {
    this.success = false;
    this.Failed = true
    this.addTnxBtn = false;
  }
})
```

}

2) Recreate the Dashboard component and call the function to re-bind. The dbcomponent.ngOnInit is supposed to call api service and rebind the data to Dashboard

```
saveTransaction() {
this.addTnxBtn = true;
this.services.addNewSwiftTransaction(this.newTnx).subscribe((data) => {
  if (data.mStatus == "Success") {
    this.success = true;
    this.addTnxBtn = false;
    this.Failed = false;
    let dbcomponent = new DashboardComponent(this.services);
    dbcomponent.ngOnInit();

  } else {
    this.success = false;
    this.Failed = true
    this.addTnxBtn = false;
  }
})
```

}

```
ngOnInit() {
this.count = new dashboardClass()
this.services.getDashboardCount().subscribe((data) => {
  if (data.mStatus == "Success") {
    this.dashData = data.responseData
  } else {
    console.log(data.mStatus)
  }
})
```

}

So I am stuck with the question can I refer already loaded Dashboard component from my menu component? Are there any other ways to reload a component again to do rebind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is communication between the components.

1. Create a service with a `BehaviourSubject` and subscribe it in the Dashboard component where in you can fetch the response again.
2. Whenever you add a new record from the modal, emit the value and you will get a hit in dashboard where you have subscribed to get the grid data again.

This way you won't have to reload the page also.

Comment: Hi Manish. I saw a similar example of you answer in https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. But I dont actually have a parent child relationship between Dashboard component and my menu component. Is it still possible to achieve it using the BehaviourSubject?

Comment: With some research on component interaction via service, I finally got it to work as you said. In the link, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service I have taken "Parent child communication via service" as an example and it works the way you had described!!!!. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

After doing your stuff you can use Router.Navigate as used below:

```
constructor() {private _router: Router}
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
            return false;
 }; // to reload your component on same page
this._router.navigate(['/fsf']); // this will work
```

Comment: I have put this code and it is not reloading the component. Infact the reload is supposed to call a api and re-bind but I am not really seeing it in the chrome debugger.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo for the same?

Comment: Suraj, Unfortunately I could not share it in stackblitz as it is part of a big code base.